# How to avoid duplicating Lambda Expression in Short If?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to avoid writing lambda expression twice when it comes inside a short if? I constantly find myself in this situation and the only way I know is writing it again!

For the sake of giving an example, here is a case I needed to check for the length of a string!

```
communications.Select(c => new XElement("node",
    new XAttribute("guid", Guid.NewGuid()),
    new XAttribute("title", c.CommunicationDetails.Where(x => x.CultureCode == culture).FirstOrDefault().Title.Length < 40 ? c.CommunicationDetails.Where(x => x.CultureCode == culture).FirstOrDefault().Title : c.CommunicationDetails.Where(x => x.CultureCode == culture).FirstOrDefault().Title.Substring(0, 40)),
    new XAttribute("isHidden", false))))
```

Comment: given that `FirstOrDefault()` can return `null`, `FirstOrDefault().Title` is a `NullReferenceException` waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Func<IEnumerable<CommunicationDetails>, string> getFirstDtlTitle = ((dtls) => dtls.Where(x => x.CultureCode == culture).FirstOrDefault()?.Title ?? "");

communications.Select(c => new XElement("node",
                               new XAttribute("guid", Guid.NewGuid()),
                               new XAttribute("title", getFirstDtlTitle(c.CommunicationDetails).Length < 40 ? getFirstDtlTitle(c.CommunicationDetails) : getFirstDtlTitle(c.CommunicationDetails).Substring(0, 40)),
                               new XAttribute("isHidden", false))))
```

Would be the first stab at the refactor.

Although I would also make an extension method for string to trim to max length so you would only need one call to the lambda.

So you would end up with something like this

```
Func<IEnumerable<CommunicationDetails>, string> getFirstDtlTitle = ((dtls) => dtls.Where(x => x.CultureCode == culture).FirstOrDefault()?.Title ?? "");

communications.Select(c => new XElement("node",
                               new XAttribute("guid", Guid.NewGuid()),
                               new XAttribute("title", getFirstDtlTitle(c.CommunicationDetails).TrimToLength(40),
                               new XAttribute("isHidden", false))))
```

Comment: Many correct answers were given but I liked how you created a delegate function to handle it

Comment: @EGN The repetition in code is gone, which is, no doubt, a great improvement upon the original. However, run-time repetition did not go anywhere, because `FirstOrDefault()` gets called twice.

Comment: Not with the extension method. It gets chained.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can benefit from the fact that `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`:

```
new string(Title.Take(40).ToArray()) //Take will take 40 first elements or as many as there are if less than 40.
```

Or

```
string.Concat(Title.Take(40))
```

Probably not as performant but much more readable and less error prone due to code duplication.

As as commented, `FisrtOrDefault().Title` is a `NullReferenceException` waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of a missing string API. Write a method that lets you pass a string, and take at most 40 characters:

```
static class StringExtensions {
    public static SubstringUpTo(this string str, int len) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (len < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(len));
        }
        return len >= str.Length ? str : str.Substring(0, len);
    }
}
```

This lets you avoid getting the string for the second time:

```
new XAttribute(
    "title"
,   c.CommunicationDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CultureCode == culture)
    ?.Title.SubstringUpTo(40)
)
```

Note the use of `?.` operator to handle situations when there is no item with the `CultureCode` that you need, and `null` handling inside `SubstringUpTo` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

I think best option is to extract title logic to separate method. That will make things more efficient, more readable and more testable.

```
communications.Select(c => new XElement("node",
    new XAttribute("guid", Guid.NewGuid()),
    new XAttribute("title", BuildTitle(c)),
    new XAttribute("isHidden", false))))


private string BuildTitle(CommuncationDetails c)
{
    var culturedDetails = c.CommunicationDetails.Where(x => x.CultureCode == culture).FirstOrDefault();

    if (culturedDetails == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(culturedDetails.Title)) return string.Empty;

    return culturedDetails.Title.Substring(0, Math.Min(40, culturedDetails.Title.Length));
}
```